# Tradeoffs between Testability and Performance when filtering using SQL vs LINQ

Tags: .net, sql, asp.net-core, linq, dapper

My team has recently decided to adopt the CQRS pattern similar to the one used in the famous [Microsoft **EShopsOnContainers** repository](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers). In this solution, the queries are made in Query classes using Dapper and Commands are done in command handlers using **EF Core**.

The queries that I am doing on my domain are quite complex and require a lot of filtering of the data. Without using **LINQ**. I am relying on using purely dynamic **SQL** statements *(not my strong point)* to query my domain model with multiple `WHERE` clauses etc.

This approach would make it extremely hard to unit test my queries.

**Here are the two approaches I am considering:**

**Approach 1:**

```
string sql = @"
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vw_LogisticsManagement] 
    WHERE ([Status] NOT IN @WorkOrderStatuses )
    AND ([PickupDate] IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (0 = (DATEDIFF (day, [PickupDate], getdate()))
    AND (0 != (DATEDIFF (day, [CheckInDate],  getdate())))
    ORDER BY [PickupDate]";

//Add parameters etc...
var result = await connection.QueryAsync<viewModel>(sql, parameters);
```

> Advantages:

- Very Performant

> Disadvantages:

- Difficult to test
- Difficult to write *(for someone without much SQL experience)*

**Approach 2**

```
string sql = @" SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vw_LogisticsManagement] 
var result = await connection.QueryAsync<viewModel>(sql, parameters);

var wos = result.Where(wo => wo.PickupDate.HasValue
                && wo.PickupDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
                && wo.CheckInDate.Value.Date != DateTime.Now.Date
                && wo.Status != Status.Shipped 
                && wo.Status != Status.PartiallyShipped)
                .OrderBy(wo => wo.PickupDate).ToList();
```

> Advantages:

- Very easy to write *(someone with a lot of **LINQ** experience)*
- Easy to test filters: I could mock the result that Dapper returns (no need for in memory db) and then have a predefined list that I could apply the filters using **LINQ** and have an expected result

> Disadvantages:

- Not as performance. Enough to even matter?

So basically I am trying to weigh out the pros and cons of each, in my opinion testability outweighs the potential performance boost in this case, however not everyone from my team would be likely to agree.

Ultimately approach 1, with proper testing in place would be ideal as many of the queries I am dealing with are far more complicated.

Comment: Depending on how many records are in `[dbo].[vw_LogisticsManagement]`, your most expensive performance cost is probably the amount of network traffic an unfiltered query (Approach 2) is going to cause.

Comment: That `SELECT *` is also some potentially low-hanging fruit that may be costing you performance in *both* approaches.

Comment: In any case, I'm glad to see someone else out there who can clearly see the advantages of using a micro-orm like Dapper.  Not sure what, if anything, this question has to do with CQRS, though.

Comment: All that said, I use *both* approaches, depending on the specific situation.  If I need to keep a small dataset in memory and apply different filters to it, I'll use the second approach.  If I need retrieve a one-time, highly-focused data set as quickly as possible, I'll use the first approach.

Comment: By the way, the query in your second approach can be written as `connection.GetAll<viewModel>()` if you're using Dapper.Contrib, and you'll benefit from some caching provided by Dapper.Contrib if you decide to save any modified records.

Comment: Testing?  Honestly, I don't do a lot of automated testing on databases or data access layers.  I write my query in SSMS, look at the output to make sure it's what I want, drop the SQL into a Dapper query, check the Dapper query's return result, and generally leave it at that.

Comment: Thank you very much
1. Can you expand on what you mean by network traffic on an unfiltered query can cause.
2. The SELECT * is because I am using a view in these examples so it already contains all necessary data.
3. Correct, I guess it doesn't have to do much with CQRS itself, more specifically with queries
4.I will try the GetAll! 
5. Normally I would agree with you on this and wouldn't test my data acces layer either, but because of all the date diff queries, it adds a bit of complexity to the mix

Comment: Your first query only sends the records matching your WHERE clause over the wire.    Your second query sends every record in the table.

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to use EF on the Query side? Wouldn't that solve your problem, I mean, it's probably performant enough and allows you to query directly into the database with LINQ.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that actually makes a lot of sense. I will be filtering on massive rows of data, which would require sending a lot of data over the wire so option 1 would make a lot more sense in this case. I will simply rely on integration testing rather than unit testing

Comment: @RikD yea I was trying to figure out the tradoffs between the two. Dapper using direct SQL statements for performance benefit might out weigh the testability aspect after RobertHarvey clarified some things for me

Comment: You can execute raw queries in EF Core as well. You can combine both LINQ and raw queries. When LINQ simple enough you can test it with In-Memory option, when query is complex, use raw query and test it against actual database. "Use right tool for the job"

Comment: @Fabio was not aware that EF Core could do that. However dapper being a micro ORM would mean it is generally more performant than a fully featured ORM like EF. This has been confirmed via several benchmark tests. However I believe the benchmarks are referring to the mapping part, rather than the query itself. You are correct in using the right tool for the job and I will try and take your advice and use a balance of both.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: in regards to never testing your data access layer, you are thinking like a developer ;-) I have been known to write extensive tests for a database query, because it was not trivial filtering and sorting logic. I don't, however, write automated tested for all my queries. Just the really gnarly ones.

Comment: "This approach would make it extremely hard to unit test my queries." You cannot unit test a database query. You can unit test code related to the traversal and transformation of objects coming back from such a query, but that's it. Your unit tests should focus on what you do with your objects after you've fetched them, and you should have separate integration and stress testing on your database to test how performant your queries are.